# Can I specify additional scope in Google Auto Sign-in?

Tags: google-identity

I am trying to access user's google drive while logging them in the site using google's auto sign-in described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)

Is that possible to get for google user's permission for google drive while the user tap on the **agree to sign in** button automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you can't. You need to setup a consent form and ask for the google drive scope. This [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) should get you started.